# In Python, with subprocess.Popen, is it possible to pass literal quotes to the command to be run, when Popen's command line parameter is in list form?

Tags: python, popen

In Python, with subprocess.Popen, is it possible to pass literal quotes as an argument, when the command and its parameters are in list form?

I'll explain further what I mean. Some commands can have literal quotes in their arguments e.g. I'm trying `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`  Some might even require them.

Note that one answer points out that technically it is possible to get Chrome from the command line to launch whatever profile, without passing a literal quote `C:\Users\User>"C:\Program Files....\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Profile 2"`

Nevertheless, i'm asking about passing  literal quotes so  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

For simplicity's sake i'll use calc.exe since it's in the path.

```
import time
import subprocess

proc=subprocess.Popen("calc.exe"+" "+'--profile-directory="Profile 3"')
proc2=subprocess.Popen(["calc.exe",'--profile-directory="Profile 4"'])

time.sleep(3)

proc.wait()
proc2.wait()
```

Now look at the difference in the command line as visible in task manager or via wmic.

```
    C:\Users\User>wmic process where caption="calc.exe" get commandline  | findstr calc
    c:\windows\system32\calc.exe --profile-directory="Profile 3"
    c:\windows\system32\calc.exe "--profile-directory=\"Profile 4\""
    
    C:\Users\User>
```

You can see this from the python interpreter

```
    >>> subprocess.Popen(["c:/windows/system32/calc.exe","abc"+'"'+"def"])
    ...
    >>>
    >>> subprocess.run("C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe process where caption=\"calc.exe\" get commandline")
    ...
    c:/windows/system32/calc.exe abc\"def
    
    ....
    >>>
```

You see it's sticking a backslash in there.

---

Some comments regarding some suggestions given.

One suggestion assumes that `--profile-directory="Profile 1"` is the same as `--profile-directory "Profile 1"` i.e. the assumption that you can replace the = with a space and chrome will work the same.  But that isn't the case. So writing `subprocess.Popen(["C:\...\chrome.exe", "--profile-directory", "Profile 3"])`  will  indeed produce  `"C:\....\chrome.exe" --profile-directory "Profile 1"` but that won't work.. it leads chrome to either not open at all, or to open a browser window that offers profiles to click on. The equals sign is necessary.

Another suggestion does

```
subprocess.Popen(
    " ".join(
        [
            "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
            '--profile-directory="Person 1"',
        ]
    )
```

That's not passing a list to Popen, that's passing a list to join, and join is converting it to a string.

Another suggestion is

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 3"')
```

That's using a string. But as you see from my question, I managed it using a string.  I'm asking about using a list.

Another suggestion suggested `"--profile-directory='Profile 1'"`

If I run chrome with --profile-directory="Profile 1" I get a particular profile that I use sometimes. But if   running chrome with  "--profile-directory='Profile 1'" Then it doesn't load up that profile. It loads up a blank profile. And going to chrome://version shows "'profile 1'" rather than "profile 1" It's like a different profile, like you may as well have said `chrome.exe --profile-directory="profile A"`. And it also creates directories starting with `'` like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\'Profile 1234'` that should be removed.

Another suggestion suggested

```
subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
        "--profile-directory=Profile 1",
    ]
```

That is interesting because it does `"C:\...chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Profile 1"`

And it does infact load chrome with the specified profile. Though it doesn't try to pass literal quotes!

---

My question asks about when passing literal quotes. It's as if maybe it assumes it's a linux shell and inserts a backslash before it, which in a linux would ensure the quote makes it past the shell and to the program being run. Though i'm not sure it'd even go to the linux shell on linux. e.g. on Windows if I stick a cmd escape character in there like `^` so "--pro^file-directory=Profile 1" then the ^ just gets passed literally. So the cmd shell doesn't intervene.

Why is it that on Windows, subprocess.Popen calls list2cmdline when passed a list, which(and here's the big 'why'), then adds a backslash to any literal double quote within a string, meaning that  when using the 'method' of passing a list to to Popen rather than passing a string to it, there is this problem, that you can't pass a literal double quote! So, why does it add that backslash!

I did here a suggestion that looking at argsv in windows vs linux might show a difference.   I'm not sure that they would since both implement C.

I don't see why POpen in any situation should behave like Windows needs a backslash inserted more than Linux does.

```
    $ cat ./testargs.py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import sys
    print(sys.argv)
    
    C:\blah>type .\testargsw.py
    import sys
    print(sys.argv)
```

in both cases

```
    C:\blah>.\testargsw.py abc\^"def
    ['C:\\Users\\User\\testargsw.py', 'abc"def']
    
    >.\testargsw.py abc\"def
    ['C:\\Users\\User\\testargsw.py', 'abc"def']
    
    C:\blah>
    
    $ ./testargs.py abc\"def
    ['./testargs.py', 'abc"def']
```

Maybe Windows , specifically the MS C Runtime.. The Code responsible for sending a program's arguments received from the shell, to the main method into argv, is requiring an extra backslash, in a sense because after escaping the double quote, a backslash is then required. (And [here] is put in by the user).

That said, I have heard though that looking at what a shell does on Linux is basically misleading, because a major part of the purpose of the subprocess module is to ensure that you can avoid using a shell entirely.

The script example is perhaps not that relevant(it was just something somebody suggested I check), but my issue is that POpen when passed a list is adding in a backslash as shown by WMIC output(also visible in task manager in the command line column).

**added**

I spoke to a person that has used python for a long time. They said subprocess was added somewhere in 2.x  They still use os.popen(). That takes a string not a list.  There have been moves to shift people from os.popen to subprocess.Popen https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

An issue with subprocess.Popen in Windows, is it has this  list feature, that I think behaves funny.

The easy workaround to that is to not use the list feature of it. To not pass it a list. It's a new feature and not necessary. You can pass it a string.

The question includes an example from the python interpreter and shows how (on windows at least), python adds a backslash to the literal quote.

The person I spoke to pointed out to me two documents that relate to that.

A string is a sequence. A sequence could be a string or list or tuple, though in this document they use the term sequence to just mean list or tuple, and they don't mean string when they say sequence.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0324/

"class Popen(args........."
"args should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments"

It mentions about on unix, shell=True and shell=False

And then it says
"On Windows: the Popen class uses CreateProcess() to execute the child program, which operates on strings. If args is a sequence, it will be converted to a string using the list2cmdline method. Please note that not all MS Windows applications interpret the command line the same way: The list2cmdline is designed for applications using the same rules as the MS C runtime."

Technically a string is  a sequence, but that document uses the term sequence in a funny way. But what it means is it's that on Windows, if args is not given a string, but is given a list or tuple, then it uses the list2cmdline method.

Be sure to use print otherwise it uses repr() of the string

```
    >>> print(subprocess.list2cmdline(['a', '"b c"']))
    a "\"b c\""
    >>>
```

so that's the function that it's using behind the scenes, on windows, that is inserting a backslash in there.

The guy I spoke to pointed me to this document too

https://bugs.python.org/issue11827

a technical user comments, "list2cmdline() in subprocess is publicly accessible (doesn't begin with underscores) but it isn't documented."

And the point is made there that, let's say they made list2cmdline() private, the fact is that what Popen is doing to the list, in Windows, to get the command line, is undocumented.

So the question then becomes, what is the design  trying to do, what is the justification for the insertion of backslash.  If a programmer wanted to insert a backslash they could do so.  It seeems to me to make more sense then to avoid passing a list to subprocess.POpen.

Windows cmd doesn't even use backslash as an escape character!!!! It uses caret.

```
C:\Users\User>echo \\
\\

C:\Users\User>echo ^\
\

C:\Users\User>
```

it's linux eg bash, that uses  backslash as an escape character

```
$ echo \\
\

$
```

Some executables in windows might want a quote escaped and with a backslash, but then the technical user can do that just as a technical linux user does.

So given that they haven't even documented the "feature" (or bug), how they would justify it, I don't know, but they could start by documenting it!

So I don't understand why passing a list to subprocess.ppopen is adding a backslash?

I could take the list join it with space and pass it as a string to popen, so it won't add a backslash, but as mentioned, that'd be avoiding the question.

Comment: What exactly will work is platform-dependent. On other platforms than Windows, the answer is simply "yes, of course, trivially" but you might want to emphasize that you are looking for an answer for Windows victims.

Comment: @tripleee why should it not support windows? (by the way I use the command line in windows as much as many linux users and I use cygwin sometimes which gives me a lot of linux commands.. If I wanted to run a server then sure linux is better. .. But debates as to windows vs linux aside.. It should support Windows! - as well as linux)

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what I'm saying. The `subprocess` interface is unfortunately quite leaky, and so the shenanigans required on Windows to get this to work are quite different from how it works on saner platforms.

Comment: @tripleee well what justification is there for the insertion of a backslash, which a programmer is capable of putting in themselves if  they want to.. See the example I give from the python interpreter

Comment: That's a basic misunderstanding of Python strings, and a common FAQ. Python displays a tab as `\t` and a newline as `\n` and a literal backslash as `\\ ` in the `repr` format of a string.

Comment: @tripleee Can you quote where is "a basic misunderstanding of Python strings"  where I used a repr representation of a string?

Comment: When you `print(sys.argv)` you are printing a list, which gets converted into the `repr` of each list member, wrapped in `[...]`.

Comment: @tripleee fine but that's near the end of the question, and where did I state something that shows a misunderstanding of it?

Comment: You think a backslash is being added where it isn't. Try `print(sys.argv[0])`

Comment: @tripleee i'm not claiming that a backslash is being added in those script examples. I'm claiming that list2cmd or subprocess.POpen when passed a list, adds a backslash to the command line as shown by the wmic output I showed, which is visible in task manager too under the command line tab

Answer (score 0):

> In Python, with subprocess.Popen, is it possible to pass literal
> quotes as an argument, when the command and its parameters are in list
> form?

I think yes, but to elements of argsv, not to the command line..

> I'll explain further what I mean. Some commands can have literal
> quotes in their arguments e.g. I'm trying `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`  Some might even require them.
>
> Note that one answer points out that technically it is possible to get
> Chrome from the command line to launch whatever profile, without
> passing a literal quote `C:\Users\User>"C:\Program Files....\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Profile 2"`
>
> Nevertheless, i'm asking about passing  literal quotes so
> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

I think there  was some confusion, that I might have resolved now.

When running a binary executable in windows(so, an exe, not a bat file) and giving it arguments

People often speak of how linux and windows behave differently..

Windows doesn't separate arguments out, it just dumps stuff to the command line. And there's no concept of space separating out arguments.

Apparently in linux, the command line is parsed by the shell and split into arguments and the arguments are passed by the shell to a POSIX function called execv, which then get passed to main's argsv.

Whereas in windows, there's an aspect of C pertaining to Windows called the MS C Runtime, that parses the command line and splits it into arguments.

So when looking in task manager or from WMIC, at the command line, it's just a dump when it comes to quotes. The quotes aren't some special some literal. But when the MS C Runtime looks at it then the quotes will have that meaning of some special some literal, a special one will not go to argsv, and a literal one will. Usually they are all special, none are literal.

```
>calc """"""""""^G

>wmic process where caption="calc.exe" get commandline  | findstr calc
calc  """"""""""G
```

One we see what's in the command line then one can consider what the arguments are.. what would would go to argsv.

In the case of the two Chrome examples, there's actually no literal quote, in the sense of a literal quote that'd go to argsv. in either example

Example 1

`"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

Example 2

`"C:\Program Files....\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Profile 2"`

Looking at "Example 1"

It's not that there's an argument   --profile-directory="Profile 1"  that has two literal quotes.

The quotes when read by MS CRT(MS C runtime), will just preserve space keeping that "1" as part of the same argument.

So a program that displays argv will show

```
C:\blah>type w.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while (argv[i]) {
                printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}

C:\blah>w.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"
argv[0] = w.exe
argv[1] = --profile-directory=Profile 1

C:\blah>
```

See, no literal quotes there

Infact both different command lines, will produce the same thing going to argv

```
>w.exe "--profile-directory=Profile 1"
argv[0] = w.exe
argv[1] = --profile-directory=Profile 1

>w.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"
argv[0] = w.exe
argv[1] = --profile-directory=Profile 1

>
```

So, how would you even get a literal quote there, well, this link mentions it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170

the find command might have funny parsing, but if you are using find or a windows implementation of grep.. and wanted to look for a quote.. Then, you'd want one of the argsv parameters to contain a quote.

And that's when you'd put a backslash in there

```
>w.exe \"
argv[0] = w.exe
argv[1] = "

>
```

The command line would have a backslash.. So that the argv would have a literal quote.

And that's what passing a list to subprocess.Popen is all about..

You are putting in what you want to be in the argv.

It is then producing the command line that would result in those things being in the argv.

That's why it's inserting a backslash before the double quotes!

So..

When I trying to use list, I was under the mistaken impression that I needed to get literal quotes into the arguments. And I thought I was forming the command line. Both of those premises were wrong.

I suppose if a python script has two options.. one to run an executable for linux users, and one to run an executable for windows users. The command line might be different, because on the one hand, the windows command line (either what's typed or it, what windows dumps as it),  and on the other hand, what's typed on the linux command line.

And with using a list where each element is an element of argsv, it lets the library do the work, in the case of windows, using the list2cmd function, to produce whatever the command line would be in order for the MS C Runtime to produce the result you want in argsv.

**side note**

```
    In the testargs.py file used in the question, it'd not give expected output https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170 for some strings e.g. `"ab\"c" "\\" d`   because it is giving the repl representation  Adjust it as follows.
    
    user@comp:~# cat ./testargs.py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import sys
    print(sys.argv)
    
    user@comp:~# cat ./testargs_corrected.py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import sys
    
    # print(sys.argv) would behaves unintended for "ab\"c" "\\" d
    # (it's escaping strings  for output in an repr)
    # so not using print(sys.argv), using below line instead.
    # '//' that it shows, means / 'cos '//' is a single character in python
    # but much clearer to show it not in the repl form.

    for n, a in enumerate(sys.argv): print(f"argv[{n}] = {a}")
    
    user@comp:~# ./testargs.py "ab\"c" "\\" d
    ['./testargs.py', 'ab"c', '\\', 'd']
    user@comp:~#


    user@comp:~# ./testargs_corrected.py "ab\"c" "\\" d
    argv[0] = ./testargs_corrected.py
    argv[1] = ab"c
    argv[2] = \
    argv[3] = d
    user@comp:~#
```

Answer (score -1):

Should do the trick (*might wanna pass `shell=True` to Popen if it doesn't*):

```py
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--profile-directory", "Profile 3"]);
```

This is possible because `--some-flag="some value"` is the same as `--some-flag "some value"`

ChRomE solution (working, omg):

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
        "--profile-directory=Profile 1",
    ]
)
```

Comment: You write "This is possible because --some-flag="some value" is the same as --some-flag "some value"" <-- Not for chrome it doesn't!  Chrome requires the = there. Replacing it with a space doesn't work. Chrome then either doesn't start at all, or it starts it but doesn't go to the profile and just shows a list of profiles and you click on the one you want.

Comment: This is common alternate syntax for passing flags with values 99% of the time, perhaps this is an exception. `subprocess.Popen('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 3"')` should work

Comment: Well, see  the question, the title, the first paragraph, and throughout,  I showed that non-list variation working, so I know that works, but I asked specifically about when the command and its parameters are in list form

Comment: Yeah, downloaded chrome, funny stuff, I guess they wrote their own cli arguments parser and it works like dogs*** but I got a solution, updated the answer.

Comment: well, I can see u aren't passing a list to Popen. U just took a list and used join to convert it into a string! One could use a string to start with. Though I was wondering about passing a list to POpen. It looks like it can't be done.. so then I wonder.. Why can't it.. Why is Popen behaving that way.. Is it that in the list case, (passing a list to Popen), it acts like it's for passing to a linux shell.. 'cos linux would strip out the quotes and so requires they be escaped with `\\`  (cont)

Comment: (cntd)  So if you stick a literal quote in an argument to the list, Popen assumes you want it escaped and linux style, and does it for you automatically (though in this case / on windows, such behaviour is unwanted). And such behaviour isn't even necessary on linux either 'cos if the programmer wants quotes escaped he can escape them himself!  If that's what's happening then Popen is trying to be clever and doing it badly, it's even buggy for it to do that. 'cos this is windows not linux.

Comment: `"--profile-directory='Profile 1'"` works fine with the list approach, smh. Also, `--profile-directory=Default` is not the same as `--profile-directory="Default"`, even in cmd, which is.. how tf your parser works guys...

Comment: No it's not the same at all.  If I run chrome with `--profile-directory="Profile 1"` I get a particular profile that I use sometimes.  But if I or I suppose you, run chrome with your suggestion.  "--profile-directory='Profile 1'"  Then it doesn't load up that profile. It loads up a blank profile. And going to chrome://version shows "'profile 1'" rather than "profile 1"  It's like a different profile, like you may as well have said "--profile-directory="profile A"

Comment: You are actually true, I checked local appdata and it has folders with ' in the names, but now I found the solution, and it is simple - don't put any quotes at all 

Comment: Doing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=Profile 2 and it thinks 2 is a URL and tries to go to http://0.0.0.2/

Comment: I think you are onto something in your update..  'cos this works You did it passing a list to POpen, and got chrome started, though you did it without passing a literal quote, but still pretty good!!!`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "--profile-directory=Profile 2"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247242/discussion-between-barlop-and-daniel).